# Magento 1.9 add layout and template to custom module in admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I try to create custom module that shows on main page two tabs with option to change titles, backgrounds, colors.

I successfully add the module tab in admin and can't add layout and template.
I'm stuck.

Can any one explain, please, how I can do this?

Here are the `xml` files that I got:

**config.xml**

```
       <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
     <modules>
    <Lern_Sample>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Lern_Sample>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <sample>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Lern_Sample</module>
                <frontName>sample</frontName>
            </args>
        </sample>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <sample>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Lern_Sample</module>
                <frontName>admin_sample</frontName>
            </args>

        </sample>
    </routers>
</admin>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <sample>
            <class>Lern_Sample_Helper</class>
        </sample>
    </helpers>
</global>
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <sample module="sample">
            <title>Sample Module</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <sample module="sample">
                    <title>Sample Module</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>admin_sample/adminhtml_index</action>

                    <layout>
                        <lern_sample>
                            <file>lern_sample.xml</file>
                        </lern_sample>
                    </layout>
                </sample>
            </children>
        </sample>
    </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

**module xml etc/Lern_Sample.xml**

```
           <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Lern_Sample>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Adminhtml />
        </depends>
    </Lern_Sample>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own layout file by declaring it under the node `<frontend>`, just like this :

```
<layout>
    <updates>
        <sample>
            <file>sample.xml</file>
        </sample>
    </updates>
</layout>
```

Your layout file will have to be located under `app/design/frontend/MY_CUSTOM_PACKAGE/MY_DEFAULT_THEME/layout/sample.xml` or under the base installation `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sample.xml`

If you try to add a layout update file for the admin, just use this code sample under the node `<adminhtml>`.